\hrule and text does not obey \hoffset
I have following code in which I am trying to make a slide:
\input eplain
\beginpackages
  % |url.sty| provides the |\url| command which we will use to typeset
  % a URL.  We request that |url.sty| be the version from June~27,
  % 2005, or later, because earlier versions had problems interacting
  % with plain \TeX.
  \usepackage{url}[2015/06/27]
  % |color.sty| provides support for colored text; all hyperlinks are
  % automatically colored by Eplain when this package is loaded.  We give
  % the |dvipsnames| option because we want to use named colors from the
  % |dvips| graphics driver.
  \usepackage[dvipsnames]{color}
  % Finally, we load |graphicx.sty|, for the macros |\includegraphics|
  % and |\rotatebox|.
  \usepackage{graphicx}
\endpackages
\enablehyperlinks
\hlopts{bwidth=0}
% \hlopts[url]{colormodel=named,color=Black}
\pdfpagewidth = 281mm
\pdfpageheight = 158mm
\hsize = 270mm
\hoffset = 5mm
\voffset = 5mm
\vsize = 145mm
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0.7}
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\font\titlefont  = cmss10 at 27pt
\font\authorfont = cmss10 at 16pt
\begingroup
  \nopagenumbers
  \topglue 0pt plus 1fill
  \titlefont{\color{mycolor}Red-Black Tree}
  \vskip 5mm
  \hrule
  \vskip 5mm
  \authorfont Shiv Shankar Dayal
  \vfil
\endgroup
\bye

The problem is \hrule and text does not start where I want. It does not obey the \hoffset.

leave hoffset and voffset alone and check the eplain documentation (texdoc eplain), section margins.

Thanks a lot. I see that margins are fixed but it does not honor paperwidth or paperheight commands from eplain document. The page size in output is fixed for US letter and does not change.

well sorry but I do not intent to start to debug and extend eplain. Use a better format which properly support all these things or dig into the code yourself.

I resolved it by setting margins as suggested by @Ulrik in the comments and setting both the pdfpagewidth and paperwidth.
\input eplain
\beginpackages
  % |url.sty| provides the |\url| command which we will use to typeset
  % a URL.  We request that |url.sty| be the version from June~27,
  % 2005, or later, because earlier versions had problems interacting
  % with plain \TeX.
  \usepackage{url}[2015/06/27]
  % |color.sty| provides support for colored text; all hyperlinks are
  % automatically colored by Eplain when this package is loaded.  We give
  % the |dvipsnames| option because we want to use named colors from the
  % |dvips| graphics driver.
  \usepackage[dvipsnames]{color}
  % Finally, we load |graphicx.sty|, for the macros |\includegraphics|
  % and |\rotatebox|.
  \usepackage{graphicx}
\endpackages
\enablehyperlinks
\hlopts{bwidth=0}
% \hlopts[url]{colormodel=named,color=Black}
\paperwidth = 281mm
\paperheight = 158mm
\pdfpagewidth = 281mm
\pdfpageheight = 158truemm
\topmargin = 5mm
\bottommargin = 5mm
\leftmargin = 5mm
\rightmargin = 5mm
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0.7}
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\font\titlefont  = cmss10 at 27pt
\font\authorfont = cmss10 at 16pt
\begingroup
  \nopagenumbers
  \topglue 0pt plus 1fill
  \titlefont{\noindent\color{mycolor}Red-Black Tree}
  \vskip 5mm
  \hrule
  \vskip 5mm
  \noindent\authorfont Shiv Shankar Dayal
  \vfil
\endgroup
\bye

